# How to encrypt data in django

Tags: python, django

As we know that we had an id in Django for each item in models by using which we can access that item. Now I want to encrypt that while sending to the frontend so that the user can't enter random id in URL to access any note.
So how can I encrypt that
here is what i want

url should look thsi = notes.com/ldsfjalja3424wer0ew8r0
not like this = notes.com/45

```
class Note(models.Model):
  title = models.char
  id = model.primary

 
  def create_encryptkey():
```

And can be decoded in views if needed for any purpose for example to get exact id

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without encryption, use `UUIDField` to get url like:

`http://localhost:8000/notes/8eb81c9b-c0db-4603-8479-37b9ea13a274`

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Note(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    title = models.CharField()
```

**Update**: If you want a version without dash, you can use a custom function:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

def myuuid():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex

class Note(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=myuuid)
    title = models.CharField()
```

Comment: is this can be decoded by user i have no problem if get decoded but  justfor information

Comment: No it can't be decoded. The string is generated randomly.